# How do I download Flash player to see youtube videos?

Tags: flash, youtube

I clicked "ATP for Ubuntu 10.04+" and when I click download it asks me to choose an application. I did some searching, and ATP is not listed in my firefox  applications listing. should I have clicked on of the other linux (but not ubuntu) options?

Answer (score 0):

You can download it in Ubuntu Software Center (built in app).

To automaticly open links from eg. [http://apps.ubuntu.com](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer/) you have to specify path to software center executable in your browser - click on open with and select `/usr/bin/software-center`